# PHP AJAX jQuery cross domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my web application i've got an iframe from different domain. I wrote some jQuery scripts in iframe that should pass data from iframe to parrent window. But in fact of their are in differents domain I cant do this directly trought JS. So I figured out to send values from iframe to PHP on server 1 then send from server 1 to server 2 data to another PHP file (witch is in another iframe) and then execute PHP function witch fires up a jQuery script with my data.

To send data from iframe I must use AJAX becouse I dont wanna to refresh site while sending it. Everything goes OK, but secound PHP file isn't execute in iframe, but return whole code to AJAX response.

My question is, how can I make secound PHP file to write data to iframe that I set up src= to it?

Comment: you can use jsonp instead of ajax http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/

Comment: Are you getting PHP-code in second iframe? So something wrong is with php-script, like you forgot `<? ?>` or anything else. The second point is, that is weird to use 2 iframes to mess with data. You can send ajax  reqests to foreign domains, there aren't many security restrictions for that.

Comment: my php code in iframe is:  <?php
  if (isset($_POST["phpMap"])){
   $response = $_POST["phpMap"];
 
   echo $response;
  }
?> and echo is sending result to AJAX response insted of to iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great library for this called easyXDM:

http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Comment: i cant use any libs thats hack XSS cause of security policy.